# Swift package manager "No such module 'RealmSwift'"

Tags: swift, realm, swift-package-manager

I have created one swift package and added realm as dependency. When I am importing (import RealmSwift) one of my package file, Its giving me error - "No such module 'RealmSwift'".

this is how dependency added in package--

```
 dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
       .package(url: "https://github.com/realm/realm-swift.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "10.32.1"))
    ],
```

```
.target(
            name: "SPMCheck",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "Realm", package: "realm-swift")],
        path: "Sources"),
```

---

In class DataManager

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift.  // here error come. If I remove this line code build perfectly.
```

This code should run

Comment: Is the dot after `import RealmSwift` really in the code ?

Comment: no dot is not there in code

Comment: Can you try to change the name `Realm` in `dependencies: [.product(name: "Realm", package: "realm-swift")]` by `RealmSwift` and see if it now compiles ?

Comment: I am with @Pierre per his comment but - if you're using Realm throughout your project, why not just add it to the project as a dependency and call it done? Why `.target` at all? See [Install Realm for Apple](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/install/#installation)

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone I found solution yesterday after doing lot of comparision.

dependencies: [.product(name: "Realm", package: "realm-swift"),  .product(name: "RealmSwift", package: "realm-swift")]

Comment: @user861715 how did you fix the issue? Could you please post your final Package.swift ?